# what is an optimal way to approach this list to array problem

Tags: c#

```
    class ProjectGroup
    {
        private List<string> members = new List<string>();
        public List<string> Members { get { return members; } }

    }

    class Course
    {
        public bool AddStudent(string name)
        {
            ProjectGroup projectGroup = new ProjectGroup();

            projectGroup.Members.Add(name);
                
            return true;
        }
    }
```

So in this code I created a private list of `members` and accessed it with a public list `Members` which makes no sense for being a private in the first place. So instead I made a clone of the private list `ToArray()`.

```
    class ProjectGroup
    {
        private List<string> members = new List<string>();
        public string[] Members { get { return members.ToArray(); } }

    }
```

but that means I can't use `projectGroup.Members.Add(name);` anymore since `Members` is an array now.

How can I add `string name` to `projectGroup.Members` now?

Comment: `members` and `Members` (with capital `M`) can be confusing. i want to be sure, are `private List<string> members` and `AddStudent(string name)` method in two different classes? if no, you can manipulate `members` instead.

Comment: sorry I didn't mention about the class. the ```AddStudent``` method is in a different class of the ```members``` list.

Comment: i thought you have learned on how to provide [mcve] - please update your code to be a workable one, i saw one orphaned curly brace and two returns in a single method. if its on different class, you need to have the class that owns `members` to provide a way (methods) to interact (presumably add/remove students) with.

Comment: I edited the code. I hope that is minimal enough.

Comment: is the `members` need to be unchanging (read only) list? if you want to populate it once without allowing changes, you can use [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors). otherwise, you can provide add/remove functionality through `ProjectGroup` methods.

Answer (score 1):

The first code makes perfect sense. It's a read-only property so you can get the `List` object in order to add items or whatever but you cannot set the property, so you cannot replace the existing `List` with a completely different one. The thing is, you don't need the field at all. Just use the property:

```vb
public List<string> Members { get; } = new List<string>();
```

There will be a field created implicitly by the compiler but you don't need to use it so you don't need to declare it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

> but that means I can't use `projectGroup.Members.Add(name);` anymore since Members is an array now.

> How can I add string name to `projectGroup.Members` now?

It depends, you should ask yourself, will this `ProjectGroup.Members` changed over time or only populated once at creation time? Is the encapsulation actually worth the trouble?

### Populated Once

If it populated once, you can use [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors). This way you can ensure the `members` is read-only.

```
class ProjectGroup
{
    private List<string> members;
    public string[] Members { get { return members.ToArray(); } }
    
    public ProjectGroup(List<string> projectMembers)
    {
        //Ensure projectMembers cant be null
        if(projectMembers == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("projectMembers");
        
        members = projectMembers;
    }
}
```

You can then create an instance of the `ProjectGroup` this way:

```
var pg = new ProjectGroup(new List<string>(){"robert", "bob"});
```

### Restricting Operations

If you want to limit the number of action you can do on the `List<string>`, you can add methods to expose the functionality you required. For example, let's say we want to validate name before being added into the `members`. You can add a method in `ProjectGroup` to do so (lets call it `AddName`).

```
class ProjectGroup
{
    private List<string> members = new List<string>();
    public string[] Members { get { return members.ToArray(); } }
    
    public void AddName(string name)
    {
        //Ensure name is never empty string or null
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");

        members.Add(name);
    }
}
```

You can then add more members as such:

```
var pg = new ProjectGroup();
pg.AddName("alice");
pg.AddName("sarah");
```

You can create method for member removal in the similar fashion.